# Convert this into EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT FILE

Tags: javascript

They actually have an inline javascript code and I am trying to convert it to an external javascript file.  I want to get rid of my onclicks but I dont know how to rewrite my JS to be external. Here's the code I'm working at.

```
</div>
                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                    </div>
```

```js
    <script>
 let slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);
 function plusSlides(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }
 function currentSlide(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }
 function showSlides(n) {
 let i;
 const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
 }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You can just create another Javascript file called something like `script.js` and link it at the bottom of your HTML file like `<script src="script.js"></script>`. You won't need to rewrite your JS code. Don't forget to remove the script tags from the new JS file you created though. 
 https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: And you may want to read up on event listeners to replace the inline onClick calls.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, create `js` file. Like, `script.js`. Then, add your javascrript code inside the `script.js`. In *script.js*:

```
    let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
```

Now, add the external file to the html file. Like:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You, can add this linking line in the head or at the bottom of body.

*Note:- If you add at the top i.e, head, then script will load first before the document inside body. Else, it will load after on.